# What NS should user libraries be in?

Tags: c++, namespaces, shared-libraries

This is a continuation of my question here: [Why isn't std::begin/end being considered here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164871/why-isnt-stdbegin-end-being-considered-here)

I'm in the midst of moving my custom library code into `namespace Toolbox` - including both `contains` template and `begin` and `end` for `CStringA` and `CStringW`.

I have a template free function algorithm "contains":

```
namespace Toolbox {
template <typename collection_type, typename element_type, typename comparison_function_type>
bool contains(const collection_type & collection, const element_type & element, comparison_function_type comparison_function)
{
    using namespace ::std;
    return end(collection) != find_if(begin(collection), end(collection), [&](const element_type & candidate) { return comparison_function(candidate, element); });
}
} // NS
```

This works for the following or fails for the following depending on what's in scope (the following is at global NS):

```
static const TCHAR * kPackFiles[] = { _T("boxit"), _T("pack") };
const auto & name = filename.GetName();
if (contains(kPackFiles, name, Toolbox::case_insensitive_equal_to<Toolbox::TCHARStringPolicy>()))
    do_something_interesting();
```

The above compiles unless the following is in scope:

```
namespace Toolbox {
template <typename T>
const typename ::std::enable_if<::std::is_same<T, CStringA>::value || ::std::is_same<T, CStringW>::value, T>::type::XCHAR *
    begin(const T & str) { return str.GetString(); }

template <typename T>
const typename ::std::enable_if<::std::is_same<T, CStringA>::value || ::std::is_same<T, CStringW>::value, T>::type::XCHAR *
    end(const T & str) { return str.GetString() + str.GetLength(); }
} // NS Toolbox
```

The above is intended to extend `CStringA` and `CStringW` to offer `const char_type` iterators on them.  This generally works for other scenarios such as `for (c : my_cstring) cout << c;`

But if my `begin` and `end` overloads for `CString` are in scope, then the compiler won't even consider anything in `std` namespace!  Ugh!

So I am at a loss as to how the NS system is intended to work practically - I see the rules (now) - it only considers the nearest NS and if anything there can be made to match (despite apparently SFINAE) then the compiler stops looking and the block just fails to compile. :(

I need some way to have my library introduce classes / free functions / algorithms / types in a way that still allows for std namespace to be considered when trying to resolve overloads such as `begin` and `end` in the above example!

And I'm at a loss here.

I can certainly move all of my algorithms - such as `contains` out to global NS.  But now I feel like I'm making a mistake - weren't NSes supposed to address (unintended) name collisions explicitly?  But if I move my algorithms into global NS I'm "polluting" the global NS, and if I put them into a library NS then I'm at odds with the very NS rules that were - I thought - intended to break out of this problem?

My goal would be to be able to give clients full control of what is eligible at any given time for consideration - and not have that pre-decided by my library, but with default fall-backs so that - in this `contains` example, if the user doesn't have a better customization of begin/end for the data type involved, that a sensible default be used.  NOT stop at some other library extensions and say "Whatever, I (the compiler) give up."

I need it to continue to searching until it either finds a working match or there aren't any at all.

So:
 1. did I mess up the SFINAE in my definitions of `begin`/`end` for `CString`s?
 2. If I didn't mess that up and SFINAE is working as intended, then how do I make NSes work for me instead of against me?

Thanks for any assistance you might offer!

Comment: Contents and names of namespaces is more of an opinionated issue.  People have different opinions on how to determine the contents of a namespace.

Comment: I need "working systems" - I seem to have failed to grock the bigger picture, and NS don't work in an intuitive way for me at all.  So, fine, I misunderstood.  So, how do any of you see it in a framework that makes it genuinely work for you?  (or did I just get the enable_if wrong)?